# Angular redirecting to subdomain for a single route with standard Angular router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-routing

I have a page in my Angular app that I need to redirect to a subdomain.  So if the user visits /latino, they should be redirected to "spanish.mysite/latino".  I am new to Angular and I see the redirectTo function for the router but this will not let me redirect to a subdomain.  When I add

```
redirectTo: "latino.localhost:3000/latino",
```

The url I get is "http://localhost:3000/latino.localhost/latino".  Is it possible to do this without the UI router?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution to this was to use an external redirect in a route filter.  This is required because the Angular router considers spanish.localhost:3000 to be an external URL due to the subdomain.

Comment: Can you please give brief description to this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want it to go to the "/latino" endpoint. If so, you just need to change your code to:

```
redirectTo: "latino"
```

This will give you the url:

```
localhost:3000/latino
```

Comment: Yes I want the /latino endpoint, but I want all visits to that endpoint to prepend the subdomain.  so if the user visits mysite/latino  they should be directed to spanish.mysite/latino, so that translations show up on the page.